# How do I change the color of an infobox in shinydashboard based on a string, not a value?

Tags: r, if-statement, shiny, shinydashboard

I have been trying to change the color of the `InfoBox` if the entry is "x" or "y". I found this question here: [How do I change the color of an infobox in shinydashboard based on the value displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301306/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-an-infobox-in-shinydashboard-based-on-the-value-dis). The answer given works for numerical data, but I can't get to work with string. Here is a reproducible code that works with numerical values.

````
```{r library and source, eval= FALSE }

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

```


```{r UI, eval = FALSE}
ui <- dashboardPage(
  #Header
  dashboardHeader(title = "dashboard"),
  
  #Sidebar with download button
  dashboardSidebar(width = 130),
  
  #Body
  dashboardBody ((box
                  (
                    width = 6,
                    textInput("wt1", " Choose wt:", "")
                  )),
                 
                 infoBoxOutput("Output"))
)

```

```{r Server, eval = FALSE}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Output <- renderInfoBox({
    InfoTotal <- paste(input$wt1, "")
    
    if (input$wt1 > 2)
    {
      infoBox(
        "Change colors, please",
        InfoTotal,
        icon = icon("tint", lib = "glyphicon"),
        color = "red"
      )
    }
    else
      
    {
      infoBox(
        "Change colors, please",
        InfoTotal,
        icon = icon("tint", lib = "glyphicon"),
        color = "blue"
      )
    }
    
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

```
````

Also, it doesn't work for me is I try `if (input$wt1 = 2)` instead of `> 2`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two equal signs, e.g.  `if (input$wt1 == 2)` or `if (input$wt1 == "red")`

R treats `=` differently to `==`. The first is for assigning things while the second is for testing whether two things are equal.

Comment: Yeah, that was silly of me :P. Your answer works for my example, but it doesn't work for my shinydashboard, unfortunately. But I will have to ask the question again in another way. Thank you!